# Is there a way to insert a line break in the Visual Studio Search/Replace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to search for a specific keyword in Visual studio and replace it with a block of code without removing line breaks?

For example, I want to search for :

```
SearchKeyword
```

And replace it with :

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

Assuming, of course, that the code block above is quite long and isn't a code that I can automatically format using Visual Studio or another tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable "Use regular expressions" mode (the icon with the small square and the star), and enter `\r\n` as the code for line breaks. If you want to format your code, you might also need `\t`.

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but might be worth a mentioning for those replacing other text that when replacing regex-y characters, obviously those will need special attention in this mode.